# how to add space between 2 css borders

Tags: html, css

[2 css borders have no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omg9T.png)

I added 2 css borders in my html page using css but do not know how to add space between them. Is there any solution to this?
code:

```css
.intro{
border: 5px dotted greenyellow;

}
.formation{
   
    border: 5px dotted brown;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add margin-bottom to the top one, so there will be a gap

```css
.intro{
border: 5px dotted greenyellow;
margin-bottom:1rem;
}
.formation{

border: 5px dotted brown;
   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a margin in your intro class to give the border. Like this

```
.intro{
margin-bottom:10px;
border: 5px dotted greenyellow;
}
```